# how do i import a html form into a separate file

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I've been trying to import a html form and embedded it into a separate html file, my javascript to try and upload the file containing the form looks like this

```
    <link rel="import" href="formhtml5.html" onload="handleLoad(event)" 
     onerror="handleError(event)">
     var link = document.querySelector('link[rel="import"]');
     var el = link.import.querySelector('#flexyForm');
     document.body.appendChild(link);
```

however when I try and see if the form is uploaded my page is just blank? been struggling with this for days now and its driving me nuts, anyone got any guesses to see how it works?

Comment: You are not **uploading** anything. You are importing. There are no `<script>` tags around your JS... You haven't posted the `handleLoad` function. We don't know what is inside formhtml5.html. Do you get any JS errors?

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you're looking for, it's possible with jQuery.

firstFile.html

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#includeForm").load("formFile.html"); 
});
</script> 
</head> 

<body> 
 <div id="includeForm"></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

formFile.html

```
<p>This is my Form</p>
```

**Note:** Your question is not clear, you're not uploading anything. Instead you're just **importing** some lines of code from another html file to yours. If yes, above code should work fine!

Also, If the included HTML file has CSS attached to it, it might mess up your page style. So better to do internal CSS or change the CSS external link in formFile as per link rules of firstFile.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also use php in additional to JS to get the content of the second file.

```
<?php file_get_contents="path to your file here" ?>
```